# Error: two or more data types in declaration specifiers

Tags: c

This color code calculator is supposed to read in different colors and calculate the resistance.

I keep getting this error on line 54:6:

> error: two or more data types in declaration specifiers

```
        #include <stdio.h>
        #include <stdlib.h>
        #include <math.h>
        #include <string.h>
        #include <stdbool.h>

        bool colorverify( char(*col)[7], const char(*r_col)[7]);
        void resist(char (*col)[7], const char(*r_col)[7]);

        void toler(char (*col)[7], const char(*r_col)[7]);
        char  ch;

        int main(void)
        {
                do
                   {

                    input:;
                    char col[6][7];
                    const char r_col[11][7]={"silver","gold","black","brown","red","orange","yellow","green","blue","violet","grey","white"};


                    printf("  Below are is a list of color that are acceptable \n");
                    printf("      black  brown  red  orange \n ");
                    printf("     yellow green blue violet grey \n");
                    printf("      white gold silver \n");
                    printf("\n Enter 4 band colors \n");

                    scanf( "%s %s %s %s ", &col[0], &col[1], &col[2], &col[3]); 

       if(colorverify(col, r_col))
                                {
                                          resist(col, r_col);
                                         toler(col,r_col);
                                }
                            else
                                {
                                        printf("Invalid color please try again");
                                        goto input;
                                }

                        }
                while( ch=='Y' || ch =='y');
        return 0;
        }

/******line 54******/  bool colorverify(char(*col)[7]), const char(*r_col)[7])
                        {
                                int i, j;
                                bool col_valid = true;
                                for(j=0; j<7;j++)
                                                        {
                                                                if (!col_valid)
                                                                        return false;
                                                                        col_valid = false;
                                                                                for(i = 0; i < 12; i++)
                                                                                        {
                                                                                                if(strncmp(col[j], r_col[i], 7) ==0)
                                                                                                        {
                                                                                                                col_valid= true;
                                                                                                                break;
                                                                                                        }
                                                                                        }
                                                        }
                                     if (strncmp(col[0], r_col[2], 7) == 0) || (strncmp(col[0], r_col[1], 7)==0) || (strncmp(col[0],r_col[0], 7)== 0)
                                                        {
                                                                return false;
                                                        }
                                        else if (strncmp(col[1], r_col[1], 7) == 0) ||(strncmp(col[1], r_col[0], 7) ==0) ||(strncmp(col[2],r_col[1], 7)==0)|| (strnc$
                                                        {
                                                                return false;
                                                         }
         else if (strncmp(col[5], r_col[7], 7) ==0) ||(strncmp(col[5], r_col[10], 7) ==0) ||(strncmp(col[5],r_col[11], 7)==0)|| (strn$
                                                        {
                                                                return false;
                                                        }
                                        else
                                                        {
                                                                return true;
                                                        }
                                }



        void resist(char(*col)[7],const char(*r_col)[7])
        {
                int i;
                double color_pts, resistance, exp;

                        for(i=0; i<4;i++)
                                {
                                        if (strncmp(col[i], r_col[0],7)==0)
                                                {
                                                        color_pts = -2;
                                                        exp= .01;
                                                }
                                        else if(strncmp(col[i],r_col[1],7)==0)
                                                {
                                                        color_pts = -1;
                                                        exp= .1;
                                                }
                                        else if(strncmp(col[i],r_col[2],7)==0)
                                                {
                                                        color_pts  = 0;
                                                        exp= 1;
                                                }
                                        else if(strncmp(col[i],r_col[3],7)==0)
          {
                                                        color_pts = 1;
                                                        exp= 10;
                                                }
                                        else if(strncmp(col[i],r_col[4],7)==0)
                                                {
                                                        color_pts = 2;
                                                        exp= 100;
                                                }
                                        else if(strncmp(col[i],r_col[5],7)==0)
                                                {
                                                        color_pts = 3;
                                                        exp= 1000;
                                                }
                                        else if(strncmp(col[i],r_col[6],7)==0)
                                                {
                                                        color_pts = 4;
                                                        exp= 10000;
                                                }
                                        else if(strncmp(col[i],r_col[7],7)==0)
                                               {
                                                        color_pts = 5;
                                                        exp= 100000;
                                                }
                                        else if(strncmp(col[i],r_col[8],7)==0)
                                                {
                                                        color_pts = 6;
                                                        exp= 1000000;
                                                }
                                        else if(strncmp(col[i],r_col[9],7)==0)
                                                {
                                                        color_pts = 7;
                                                        exp= 10000000;
                                                }
                                        else if(strncmp(col[i],r_col[10],7)==0)
                                                {
                                                        color_pts = 8;
                                                        exp= 100000000;
                                                }
                                        else if(strncmp(col[i],r_col[11],7)==0)
          {
                                                        color_pts = 9;
                                                        exp= 1000000000;
                                                }

                                        if(i == 0)
                                                {
                                                        resistance= color_pts * 100;
                                                }
                                        if(i == 1)
                                                {
                                                        resistance += color_pts * 10;
                                                }
                                        if(i == 2)
                                                {
                                                        resistance += color_pts;
                                                }
                                        if(i== 3)
                                                {
                                                        resistance = color_pts * exp;
         }

                                if(resistance < 1000000)
                                        {
                                                printf(("resistance = %.2f kOhms\n"), (resistance/1000));
                                        }
                                                else
                                        {
                                                printf(("resistance = %.2f MOhms\n"), (resistance/1000000));
                                        }



        void toler(char(*col)[7], const char(*r_col)[7])
                {
                        double tolerance;
                                if(strncmp(col[4], r_col[3], 7) == 0)
                                {
                                        tolerance = 1;
                                }
          else if(strncmp(col[4], r_col[3],7)==0)
                                {
                                        tolerance = 2;
                                }
                        else if(strncmp(col[4], r_col[3],7)==0)
                                {
                                        tolerance = 3;
                                }
                        else if(strncmp(col[4], r_col[3],7)==0)
                                {
                                        tolerance = 4;
                                }
                        else if(strncmp(col[4], r_col[3],7)==0)
                                {
                                        tolerance = .5;
                                }
                        else if(strncmp(col[4], r_col[3],7)==0)
                                {
                                        tolerance = .25;
                                }
         else if(strncmp(col[4], r_col[3],7)==0)
                                {
                                        tolerance = .1;
                                }
                        else if(strncmp(col[4], r_col[3],7)==0)
                                {
                                        tolerance = .05;
                                }
                        else if(strncmp(col[4], r_col[3],7)==0)
                                {
                                        tolerance = 5;
                                }

                        else if(strncmp(col[4], r_col[3],7)==0)
                                {
                                        tolerance= 10;
                                }
                        printf("Tolerance = +/- %.2f%%\n", tolerance);

                }
```

Comment: TL;DR -- can you please mark line 54?

Comment: Please create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), because most of your code is not part of your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in

```
void bool colorverify (char(*col)[7]), const char(*r_col)[7])
---------
//why void and bool?
```

`void` and `bool` are two different data types. You should not use both together. Please get rid of the `void` from there. You don't  need that [as per the forward declaration].

Comment: Yes that got rid of it but now in its place is :53:7: error: conflicting types for 'colorverify'

Comment: @Learningcode why you have two definitions of `colorverify()` in your code? and both with same mistake?

Comment: @Learningcode Please indent your code. Kindly make it human readable. I believe, most of the problems will be solved by that only.

Comment: @SouravGhosh edited* , so instead of "if(colorverify(col, r_col))" I should put "bool colorverify( char(*col)[7], const char(*r_col)[7]);"?

Comment: @Learningcode No, not at all. Check your code. you have another `void bool colorverify(char(*col)[7]), const char(*r_col)[7]){ ...` around line 72 or something

Comment: @Learningcode Sorry, but still your code is very hard to read.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Sorry still trying to learn on how to code correctly. void bool  was a duplicated when trying to copy code from putty.

Comment: @Learningcode It happens, but be extra careful next time, otherwise you'll be wasting your time for silly reasons like this. So, it's fixed now?

Comment: @Souravghosh  Original problem was fixed TY, but two other errors arose "error: conflicting types for 'colorverify'" and "53:35: error: expected identifier or '(' before 'const''.
"

Comment: @Sebastian  where ? tks.

Comment: In that line. There are 3 opening and 4 closing brackets. And I guess the second closing one is the wrong one.